# Что обозначает warning LNK4099 при компиляции

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток.

У меня 2 проекта, один - Addition.lib
Другой - HL_1.dll

в HL - используется Addition.lib но при компиляции HL вылетает LNK4099 где указаны некоторые классы из моего проекта Addition.lib
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно говоря хотел бы узнать на сколько данное предупредение критично и как с ним справиться ? Как я понял при просмотре некоторых статей из интернета, оно обозначает что я во время построчного дебагинга не смогу зайти внутрь описанных классов в предупреждении, верно ? Есть ли еще какие либо нюансы ?

Comment: .pdb файлы являются разработкой мс и включают в себя отладочную информацию для дебагера. Наличие такого файла позволит дебажить длл и либы, используемые в проекте, его отсутствие не накладывает каких-либо ограничений на выполнение кода.

Comment: Судя по всему у вас проект в релизе, вы генерите pdb в релизе?